# Composer autoload few paths as one namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I have this folders structure:

```
core/
core/db/
core/db/beans
```

I have classes with `namespace AAA\Core\DataBase;` in the `core/db/` and in `core/db/beans`.

In my *composer.json* file I have:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AAA\\Core\\": "core/",
            "AAA\\Core\\DataBase\\": "core/db/"
        }
    }
```

After that I can use classes from `core/` folder with `use AAA\Core\DataBase\ClassName;` but can't from `core/db/beans`. I received "Fatal error: Class not found". How can I add few folders to the same namespace? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As PSR-4 standard goes:

> When loading a file that corresponds to a fully qualified class name
>
> 1. A contiguous series of one or more leading namespace and sub-namespace names, not including the leading namespace separator, in the fully qualified class name (a "namespace prefix") corresponds to at least one "base directory".
> 2. The contiguous sub-namespace names after the "namespace prefix" correspond to a subdirectory within a "base directory", in which the namespace separators represent directory separators. The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.

Therefore, your namespaces must correspond with your folder structure.

[PSR-4 Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: So, I can't put few classes with the same namespace to different folders?

Comment: Yes, you cannot do this, because it's against the psr-4 standard, which you use for your autoloader. But you could always write your own autoloader, and register it alongside the one, which was generated by composer. Although i would advice against it, manual autoloading could seriously slow down your system.

Comment: If I'm reading the OP correctly, the question was "Can I define multiple root directories for a single namespace?" and the answer is "yes, you can." [Here is a more recent question with the correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61113156/4901390). I realize this answer is 6 years old so maybe this wasn't possible back then... just leaving a  comment to let future visitors know that this is possible.