# Same namespace with files in different folders

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to structure a project so that some code that is auto generated is in a sub folder `generated/`, but it has the same namespace as files in the parent directory.

For example I have this structure which is giving me the error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MyProject\Foo' not found`.

Is it possible to have the same namespace for 2 different files in different folders like this?

```
--lib/
----Foo.php
----generated/
----generated/Bar.php
```

`lib/Foo.php`

```php
<?php

namespace MyProject;

class Foo {
  ...
}
```

`lib/generated/Bar.php`

```php
<?php

namespace MyProject;

class Bar {

  public function __construct() {
    $foo = new Foo();
  }
}
```

My autoload section looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "MyProject\\" : "lib/"
      }
  },
```

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible. You just need to ensure `Foo.php` is `include`d at some point, either explicitly or through autoloading.

Comment: My composer.json file autoloads the entire `MyProject` namespace.

Comment: Are you also loading the auto loader…? That won’t happen if you directly invoke the generated file and it doesn’t include the auto loader for example…

Comment: I don't load the autoloader in my library, but in a project i'm consuming this library with yes I do. The reset of my files/folders under `lib/` work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Composer for autoloading. You can configure composer to search multiple directories for a given namespace.

Here is some sample configuration(assuming PSR-4 autoloading)

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "MyProject\\": ["lib/", "lib/generated"] }
    }
}
```

If you can provide the `autoload` section of your Composer project, I can provide more specific details.

Comment: I added my autoload section. I was under the impression everything under `lib/` would be searched since all my other folders (which I didn't list in my example) are correctly being found since they have a different namespace subpath.

Comment: Sub-directories have to match the namespace. For your generated folder, the namespace would need to be "MyProject\generated"

Comment: Adding the mapping for "MyProject\\" to both "lib/" and "lib/generated" as described above should work. Each directory isn't a search path, but rather an exact mapping.

Comment: I specifically didn't want my namespace to have `MyProject\generated` in it. Adding an array of both values works!

Comment: when I `dump-autoload -o` I'm getting the following notice:`Class MyProject\V1\Bar located in ~/projects/src/MyProject/Api/V1/Controllers/Bar.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.` and I've added the Controllers directory with the method you described `MyProject\\V1\\": ["src/MyProject/Api/V1", "src/MyProject/Api/V1/Controllers"]`. Seems that the project is working though

Comment: Edit: putting the parent folder (".../Api/V1") last in the array removed the notice (basically the notice was from reading the parent dir *before* the sub dirs were mapped )

Answer (score 0):

It can only only work if you include the Foo.php at the calling the function.

As you have mention you are auto-loading the whole namespace with composer. Namespaces are like a virtual directory structure. In your case every class has same namespace so its trying to look all file in same directory because of which in your case Foo.php is not getting loaded via composer.

So Its better to different namespace directory wise or include them with path.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to use namespace without using ***use*** keywork. Try to follow the below code that will help you. As you are trying to access other class you will have to access via namespace otherwise you will fail to do that. follow below code.

```
<?php

namespace MyProject;

class Foo {
  ...
}

<?php

namespace MyProject;
use MyProject\Foo;

class Bar {

  public function __construct() {
    $foo = new Foo();
  }
}
```

Hope that this will work now.

Comment: `new Foo` in a `namespace MyProject` already refers to `MyProject\Foo` without a redundant `use`. The error message even says so.